# Store hex number in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a hexadecimal number that I want to store in a database (PostgreSQL) using Eloquent

I tried the following

Migration

```
$table->bigInteger('battery')->nullable()->default(null);
```

Storing

```
$model->battery = hexdec($value)
```

This only works when `$value` such as e.g. 1000000010,000000000

But it doesn't work when `$value = FFFFFFF0002D4004`

How can I store this kind of data

Comment: A hex number would have to go in a text, char column

Comment: `bigInteger` is an integer only. If you're going to use hex values (which includes letters), the column should be a string, char, or binary.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166199/best-datatype-to-store-hexidecimal-and-hex-characters-in-the-database

Answer (score 0):

A number is a number no matter if it is in hex format or decimal one, what matters is in which format you want to save it in.

Now, in PHP `hexdec()` can return an integer or a [float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php).

The float version of the result is returned when the result exceeds the size on a **signed** integer.

for example `FFFF FFF0 002D 4004` exceeds the limit `7FFF FFFF FFFF FFFF` of the signed integer 9223372036854775807  (in 64bit version of PHP) and will be returned as a float.

To check the limit of your php installation, do `echo PHP_INT_MAX;`

once a float, you can't save it in an integer field in your database.

If your value is supposed to reach the unsiged 64bit integer limit, then i suggest you save it as a string.